# CSS solution for showing a div only once another div is out of view, or past a certain number of px

Tags: html, css

I have a div:

```
<div class="fixedbar">
<div class="boxfloat" style="width:80% !important">
    <img src="#">
</div>
</div>
```

And I'm currently using CSS to show this div only after 2 seconds have passed:

```
.fixedbar {
   animation: showBlock 0s 2s forwards;
    visibility: hidden;
    bottom: 0px ;
    left: 0 ;
    padding: 0px 0 ;
    position: fixed ;
    font-size: 16px ;
    width: 100% ;
    z-index: 99999 ;
    float: left ;
    vertical-align: middle ;
    margin: 0px 0 0 ;
}

@keyframes showBlock {
    to {visibility: visible;}
}

.boxfloat {
    text-align: center ;
    width: 90% !important;
    margin: 0 auto ;
}
```

However, I really want to make it so that it only shows after the user scrolls past another div called `#head_banner` and it's out of view, or after like 200px basically. Is there a CSS only solution for either of these so that I can only show this div after the other is out of view, essentially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no scroll-style triggers in CSS. That would require JavaScript.

The closest you could get to this with CSS only would be hiding this element behind `#head_banner` using `z-index` so that as the user scrolls past `#head_banner`, your element is revealed.

One key distinction here between the CSS and JS solutions below is that the JS solution is set to wait until the `#head_banner` element has been completely scrolled past and is off-screen before displaying. This can be easily adjusted if you would like it to display once the bottom of `#head_banner` is visible, where `#head_banner` would still take up much of the screen.

### CSS Solution

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.fixedbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 99998;
}
#head_banner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 105vh;
  background-color: #00f;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixedbar">This was hidden!</div>
<div id="head_banner">This banner covers .fixedBar</div>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra ultricies ultricies. Vivamus ornare, neque non malesuada accumsan, metus eros feugiat justo, nec porta nulla libero sed magna. Morbi vitae viverra urna. Fusce tellus ex, rhoncus non rhoncus non, suscipit ut augue. Sed tristique lectus at tincidunt consequat. Nulla a diam felis. Nulla sed lectus libero. Vestibulum gravida nisl ut hendrerit eleifend. In convallis eros eu massa pharetra, in accumsan nisi blandit.</p>
  <p>Cras ut massa porta, maximus lacus lobortis, volutpat nulla. Nullam maximus interdum diam et pulvinar. Morbi non lectus eros. Etiam sem elit, viverra quis est et, condimentum luctus metus. Donec interdum, neque id dignissim condimentum, felis sapien interdum diam, sit amet lacinia enim ipsum non massa. Nunc nec ligula faucibus, condimentum justo in, dictum arcu. Nam egestas ex vitae quam imperdiet maximus. Aliquam sit amet dolor auctor, rhoncus turpis iaculis, finibus lorem. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Duis quis dapibus lectus, vitae mattis quam. Cras posuere varius faucibus. Curabitur cursus molestie gravida. Aliquam sed mi at orci convallis scelerisque a eu urna.</p>
  <p>Nulla pellentesque vulputate elit vel facilisis. Praesent dictum porta tempus. Sed ultricies enim id risus hendrerit, at elementum ante auctor. Praesent aliquet laoreet leo, a lacinia nibh finibus eu. Proin maximus rutrum metus id dictum. Sed ultricies ligula in elementum ultricies. Nullam dapibus quis enim ac pulvinar. Nam mollis finibus vehicula.</p>
  <p>Donec at metus convallis, commodo lectus vitae, viverra nunc. Donec sed lorem orci. Integer id consectetur risus. Morbi et mi et turpis dictum vulputate at a magna. Morbi ut massa quis mauris condimentum placerat. Pellentesque mattis semper mauris, non semper sem gravida interdum. Suspendisse id egestas velit, vel vulputate velit. Cras nec turpis in felis scelerisque dignissim quis eu urna. Praesent fermentum rutrum erat. In eget justo mollis, luctus lacus luctus, mattis risus. Mauris in lectus ullamcorper, dictum purus eget, accumsan risus. Praesent posuere lobortis ipsum, eu tincidunt sapien lobortis et. Duis mattis accumsan sem sit amet viverra. Fusce pulvinar, mauris ac tempor mollis, nisi nunc pharetra lectus, eget bibendum risus lorem at mauris. Praesent non est sapien. Nunc aliquam sem a nisl pulvinar ornare.</p>
  <p>Fusce eu leo enim. Sed congue, nisl sit amet auctor eleifend, leo neque egestas metus, eget interdum felis nibh nec orci. Pellentesque gravida leo nunc, id ornare leo tincidunt eget. Nulla tincidunt eu nibh in efficitur. Ut sagittis ipsum nisi, non vulputate orci ultrices eget. Integer suscipit ligula molestie tempus egestas. Cras eros libero, consectetur a nibh eget, lobortis gravida dui. Vestibulum scelerisque semper diam. Sed pellentesque, nisi sit amet pulvinar commodo, sem turpis tristique arcu, non rhoncus augue turpis eget diam. Aenean auctor ipsum vitae commodo lobortis. Nulla magna lorem, suscipit id commodo pulvinar, condimentum at lectus. Sed vel pellentesque nisi.</p>
</div>
```

### JavaScript Solution

```js
const headBanner = document.getElementById('head_banner'),
      fixedBar = document.querySelector('.fixedbar');

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if (window.scrollY > (headBanner.offsetTop + headBanner.offsetHeight)) {
    fixedBar.classList.add('visible');
  } else {
    fixedBar.classList.remove('visible');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.fixedbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 99998;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
}
.fixedbar.visible {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
#head_banner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 105vh;
  background-color: #00f;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixedbar">This was hidden!</div>
<div id="head_banner">This banner covers .fixedBar</div>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra ultricies ultricies. Vivamus ornare, neque non malesuada accumsan, metus eros feugiat justo, nec porta nulla libero sed magna. Morbi vitae viverra urna. Fusce tellus ex, rhoncus non rhoncus non, suscipit ut augue. Sed tristique lectus at tincidunt consequat. Nulla a diam felis. Nulla sed lectus libero. Vestibulum gravida nisl ut hendrerit eleifend. In convallis eros eu massa pharetra, in accumsan nisi blandit.</p>
  <p>Cras ut massa porta, maximus lacus lobortis, volutpat nulla. Nullam maximus interdum diam et pulvinar. Morbi non lectus eros. Etiam sem elit, viverra quis est et, condimentum luctus metus. Donec interdum, neque id dignissim condimentum, felis sapien interdum diam, sit amet lacinia enim ipsum non massa. Nunc nec ligula faucibus, condimentum justo in, dictum arcu. Nam egestas ex vitae quam imperdiet maximus. Aliquam sit amet dolor auctor, rhoncus turpis iaculis, finibus lorem. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Duis quis dapibus lectus, vitae mattis quam. Cras posuere varius faucibus. Curabitur cursus molestie gravida. Aliquam sed mi at orci convallis scelerisque a eu urna.</p>
  <p>Nulla pellentesque vulputate elit vel facilisis. Praesent dictum porta tempus. Sed ultricies enim id risus hendrerit, at elementum ante auctor. Praesent aliquet laoreet leo, a lacinia nibh finibus eu. Proin maximus rutrum metus id dictum. Sed ultricies ligula in elementum ultricies. Nullam dapibus quis enim ac pulvinar. Nam mollis finibus vehicula.</p>
  <p>Donec at metus convallis, commodo lectus vitae, viverra nunc. Donec sed lorem orci. Integer id consectetur risus. Morbi et mi et turpis dictum vulputate at a magna. Morbi ut massa quis mauris condimentum placerat. Pellentesque mattis semper mauris, non semper sem gravida interdum. Suspendisse id egestas velit, vel vulputate velit. Cras nec turpis in felis scelerisque dignissim quis eu urna. Praesent fermentum rutrum erat. In eget justo mollis, luctus lacus luctus, mattis risus. Mauris in lectus ullamcorper, dictum purus eget, accumsan risus. Praesent posuere lobortis ipsum, eu tincidunt sapien lobortis et. Duis mattis accumsan sem sit amet viverra. Fusce pulvinar, mauris ac tempor mollis, nisi nunc pharetra lectus, eget bibendum risus lorem at mauris. Praesent non est sapien. Nunc aliquam sem a nisl pulvinar ornare.</p>
  <p>Fusce eu leo enim. Sed congue, nisl sit amet auctor eleifend, leo neque egestas metus, eget interdum felis nibh nec orci. Pellentesque gravida leo nunc, id ornare leo tincidunt eget. Nulla tincidunt eu nibh in efficitur. Ut sagittis ipsum nisi, non vulputate orci ultrices eget. Integer suscipit ligula molestie tempus egestas. Cras eros libero, consectetur a nibh eget, lobortis gravida dui. Vestibulum scelerisque semper diam. Sed pellentesque, nisi sit amet pulvinar commodo, sem turpis tristique arcu, non rhoncus augue turpis eget diam. Aenean auctor ipsum vitae commodo lobortis. Nulla magna lorem, suscipit id commodo pulvinar, condimentum at lectus. Sed vel pellentesque nisi.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Both of these worked for me so I went with the JS for future flexibility. Thanks!